# A Letter to a Lady

Tags: rebus, literature

Parse the rebus to determine the words and their source.

[image]

Comment: In light of the answer (which I would not have got) how about moving the last face inside the DO_NOT sign, and replacing it with an eyeball?

Comment: I didn't know what rebus was: "a puzzle in which words are represented by combinations of pictures and individual letters; for instance, apex might be represented by a picture of an ape followed by a letter X."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> “Doubt thou the stars are fire;
>  Doubt that the sun doth move;
>  Doubt truth to be a liar;
>  But never doubt I love.”
>  - William Shakespeare, *Hamlet*

Comment: Which of these things is not like the others ...